# How to hit mouse key using python3.7 selenium

Tags: selenium, sendkeys

I have a requirements to trigger mouse keys (e.g., Up/Down) using python3.7 selenium. I found this approach below, but don't know what's the expected value for the `send_keys` call, and the "Up" and "Down". Any suggestions?

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).send_keys("**WHAT'S THE EXPECTED VALUE HERE**")
```

Comment: SendKeys is not used for such things. Actions is used. What do you mean  by up/down in case of mouse? This should help probably - http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/handling-keyboard-events-and-mouse-hover-events-using-webdriver

Comment: Your question is not clear but this seems to be a really, really basic question that could be answered by just reading the Selenium documentation and doing some tutorials. You need to spend some time educating yourself some more before asking questions.